# How to convert text of querySelectorAll nodes into JSON or CSV

Tags: javascript

I am getting two nodes lists of orderID and Name in querySelectorAll.

Here is my javascript code for selectors

```
document.querySelectorAll("orderid").forEach(a => alert(a.textContent));

document.querySelectorAll("name").forEach(a => alert(a.textContent));
```

I am getting Alert of each order id and name  that is just for testing pupose.
What I want is to create one Json or csv for text contents of orderid and name that I will use to send in Mysql databse later on.

Now I want json something like this

```
{
"1":[ "orderid", "name" ],
"2":[ "orderid", "name" ]
}
```

or

```
{
"orderid":[ "name" ],
"orderid":[ "name" ]
}
```

OR anything else or csv that will be suitable to upload this in MySQL through PHP later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks more clear if you wrap your each orderId and name elements with a parent div, and you `querySelectorAll` the parent divs. I don't think it's possible to have both key and value as variables in a JSON format. Here is what I will do (assume the length of your orderIds and names are the same):

```
const orderIds = document.querySelectorAll(".orderid")
const names = document.querySelectorAll(".name")
let records = []

for(let i=0; i < orderIds.length; i++){
  const record = {
     orderId: orderIds[i].textContent,
     name: names[i].textContent
  }
  records.push(record)
}
```

Then you send `records` to your backend and extract data from it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```js
let results = {orders:{},names:{}}

let ordersElements = document.querySelectorAll(".orderId");
let namesElements = document.querySelectorAll(".name")

ordersElements.forEach((element,idx) => results["orders"][idx] = element.innerHTML)
namesElements.forEach((element,idx) => results["names"][idx] = element.innerHTML)

console.log(results)
```

```html
<div class="orderId">1</div>
<div class="orderId">2</div>
<div class="orderId">3</div>
<div class="orderId">4</div>
<div class="orderId">5</div>


<div class="name">first</div>
<div class="name">second</div>
<div class="name">third</div>
<div class="name">fourth</div>
<div class="name">last</div>
```